# If a sequence $s_n$ of real numbers converges to $s>a$ then $s_n>a$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $s_n$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to $s>a$. Then there exists an $N>0$ such that $n>N\implies s_n>a$.

**PROOF:**
By definition of convergence in sequences we have that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies $|s_n-s|<\varepsilon$.

Choose $\varepsilon=s-a$. Then $|s_n-s|<s-a$. By properties of absolute values and inequalities we have $-s+a<s_n-s<s-a$ which implies $s_n>a$.

Is my proof rigorous, correct? I'd appreciate any comments for improvement.

Comment: Looks okay to me, do you know where you used the condition $s>a$ or did you even use it?

Comment: @kingW3 I think implicitly I assumed that $s-a>0$ since $\varepsilon>0$. Is that okay to do?

Comment: It is, you're able to use $\epsilon = s-a$ because $s-a>0\iff s>a$. You could mention it explicitly like "Choose $\epsilon=s-a>0$" but you don't really need to. I just wanted to check whether you understood that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just add, after “Choose $\varepsilon=s-a$”, that there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>N\implies\lvert s_n-s\rvert<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Something like:
"Let $\varepsilon=s-a>0$. Then, by definition of limit of sequence, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|s_n-s|<\varepsilon=s-a$ whenever $n>N$. By properties of absolute values and inequalities we have $-s+a<s_n-s$ which implies $s_n>a$ for $n>N$."

Comment: That would be just fine!